# Exception::raise(): Unimplemented Parser Node: EmptyElse

Tags: sorbet

When running srb init in a Rails app I get the following:

```
Generating /tmp/d20220723-3779490-paqj5l/reflection.rbi with 6784 modules and 142 aliases

Printing your code's symbol table into /tmp/d20220723-3779490-paqj5l/from-source.json

/home/allan/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sorbet-0.5.10206/lib/hidden-definition-finder.rb:123:in `write_constants': Your source can't be read by Sorbet. (RuntimeError)

You can try `find . -type f | xargs -L 1 -t bundle exec srb tc --no-config --isolate-error-code 1000` and hopefully the last file it is processing before it dies is the culprit.

If not, maybe the errors in this file will help: /tmp/d20220723-3779490-paqj5l/from-source.json.err
```

When I check that error file I find this:

Exception::raise(): Unimplemented Parser Node: EmptyElse

Is there a workaround to get past this error?

Comment: Well, which file came up as the culprit? that's probably a good place to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime you see `Exception::raise` in a Sorbet error message, it means there was a bug in Sorbet. You can report Sorbet bugs at https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/issues

I have created a fix for this bug here: https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/pull/6161

It will require upgrading Sorbet before you can take advantage of the fix. If you can't wait for that, you will have to hunt down the file in your codebase that uses Ruby's new `case ... in` syntax for pattern matching with an empty `else` keyword, and either delete the `else` keyword or change it to mention `else nil` instead.

Sorry for the inconvenience.

---

**In the future**, please use https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/issues to report all issues—I only happened to see this by accident today, but I normally do not monitor StackOverflow for bug reports.

---